# How to resolve the Blurness issue in print Preview of UWP?

Tags: datagrid, uwp-xaml

I am familiar with the data grid in the UWP plat form. we tried to provide the support for printing the results in  sheets. we have faced the hurdles while we print the content. In the print preview panel the content looks like blurry to the view, but in the printed sheet the contents look like normal. could your share your ideas to resolve this.

Thanks in advance for your updates.

Comment: You tried in real device or simulator?

Comment: I tried it in real device(Laptop with windows 10 OS)

Answer (score 1):

It seems it is by design.
In UWP, we use the `PrintManager` to inform Windows that an application wishes to participate in printing.

When we run the [`ShowPrintUIAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Graphics.Printing.PrintManager#Windows_Graphics_Printing_PrintManager_ShowPrintUIAsync) method, it will run the "PrintDialog.exe" that the print Preview page will be shown.

We can use the ["Inspect"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521(v=vs.85).aspx) to test the content of the print Preview page. From the following image, we can see the content is a [`Image`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image) control that render by the XAML.

[image]

For the performance, it does not render as clear as the printting result. We can not change that.
If you do want this feature, you are welcome to ask on [UserVoice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform).