# How to value changed notification from the MSDN print preview panel in UWP?

Tags: uwp-xaml

I have developed the code for print my Data Context in the UWP platform. I have access the PageDocument class and write the code for print the data. at the i am struggled at the spot and have a doubt for how to get the notification while change the property in the print panel as manually in the run time.

If anybody have the the idea to resolve my concern.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> how to get the notification while change the property in the print panel as manually in the run time.

You can subscribe [`OptionChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Graphics.Printing.OptionDetails.PrintTaskOptionDetails#Windows_Graphics_Printing_OptionDetails_PrintTaskOptionDetails_OptionChanged) event handle, once change the property in the print panel it will trigger the event and you will know property changed and which property changed. `OptionChanged` is one of the [`PrintTaskOptionDetails`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.printing.optiondetails.printtaskoptiondetails)'s events, you can get a `PrintTaskOptionDetails` instance by method [`GetFromPrintTaskOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.printing.optiondetails.printtaskoptiondetails#Windows_Graphics_Printing_OptionDetails_PrintTaskOptionDetails_GetFromPrintTaskOptions_Windows_Graphics_Printing_PrintTaskOptions_). For example:

```
 public MainPage()
 {
     this.InitializeComponent(); 
     printmgr.PrintTaskRequested += Printmgr_PrintTaskRequested;
 }
 private void Printmgr_PrintTaskRequested(PrintManager sender, PrintTaskRequestedEventArgs args)
 {  
     var deferral = args.Request.GetDeferral(); 
     task = args.Request.CreatePrintTask("Print", OnPrintTaskSourceRequrested);       
     PrintTaskOptionDetails printDetailedOptions = PrintTaskOptionDetails.GetFromPrintTaskOptions(task.Options);
     printDetailedOptions.OptionChanged += PrintDetailedOptions_OptionChanged;
     deferral.Complete();
 }
 private void PrintDetailedOptions_OptionChanged(PrintTaskOptionDetails sender, PrintTaskOptionChangedEventArgs args)
 {
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(args.OptionId);
 }
```

More details please reference the [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Printing).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion,i will really helpful for me to resolve my requirement. and i have one more question my Data context look like blurry in the preview panel, how to recover his issue, i have badly struggled in this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42019080/how-to-resolve-the-blurness-issue-in-print-preview-of-uwp

Comment: @BalamuruganR I will look into that thread once I found something I will reply or comment on that thread. By the way, if this reply already helped you, could you please mark as accepted?